# Dumping SQLite database in time interval

Tags: javascript, sqlite, xul

I have XUL desktop app which stores data in SQLite database. To prevent too much data store in DB i want to create some kind of auto dumping system for my DB. My idea is to store timestamp of last DB dump so on every app boot to check for that timestamp and if it is older than week to dump DB. Are there any other methods of cleaning db in some time intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PRAGMAs [page_count](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_count) and [max_page_count](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count) to check how much is your SQLite database filled - so you can clear database only when it is really needed.

Comment: tnx, this is what i needed